# Can't refresh Windows 8 on tablet: "The media inserted is not valid"

Tags: windows-8

I'm using [these instructions](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2410850,00.asp) to refresh Windows 8 (RTM) on my Samsung Series 7 tablet. When I got to the "Insert media" screen, I inserted a flashdrive containing only the files `en_windows_8_x64_dvd_915440.iso` (the Windows 8 installer) and `Key.txt`.

The first time I tried this, the tablet came back with the error message "The media inserted is not valid / Make sure to insert your Windows installation or recovery media."

Then I rebooted and tried again. Now I don't even get an error message--it's as if I didn't insert the flashdrive at all. The flashdrive is brand new and my PC recognizes it, so I doubt that's the issue.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is the source of the .iso file exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) (never mind the name, it works for Windows 8) and create a bootable disk using the ISO file. Merely putting the iso file on the disk won't work. It needs to be made bootable with the requisite boot sectors and everything

Comment: ^what he said. The thing is, just copy-pasting the .iso file wont't make your tablet recognize it. You might have to make it a bootable flash drive.

Comment: Thanks! After I did that the tablet recognized it, though the refresh failed. I'm just straight reinstalling Windows 8 now.

Comment: Good to know :) @Gutsygibbon Did i sound too complex? If yes, I'll make my answer simpler

Comment: haha no. Just making sure he got it :D